# Failed to queue test run: Unable to start the agent process(Visual Studio 2010)

Tags: .net, unit-testing, visual-studio-2010, ide, mstest

While trying to run all the unit tests in my solution(Visual Studio 2010) I am getting a 'Failed to queue test run xxxx@MACHINENAME 2010-06-23 14:01:36': Unable to start the agent process' error. Does anyone know what causes this particular error to occur and how to resolve it so that I can run my unit tests?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if this is still the case for Visual Studio 2010, but you could have this same scenario in Visual Studio 2008. When breaking off a unit test run (i.e. when detecting erroneous code while debugging a unit test) it would leave a process running.

The process that is hindering execution for Visual Studio 2008 and has to be killed to be able to unit test again is VSPerfMon.exe. Might be wort a look for VS2010.

Comment: Thanks for all the responses. I took the worst case measure and had to wipe out my VM that had the MSTS running.

Comment: Hi.  Just wondering why you accepted this answer if it didn't solve your problem?

Answer (score 2):

I know this question was asked long before .NET 4.5, but I've found that I get this error on VS2010 after installing .NET 4.5.

A "solution" (not the most helpful one - I know) is obviously to uninstall .NET 4.5.  I guess / hope there will be an update to Visual Studio 2010 at some point to resolve this.

**UPDATE**

I had a similar error, when trying to run tests which used TypeMock.  In order to solve the problem I opened up my solution in Visual Studio and selected *Test* - *Edit Test Settings*.  In the *Test Settings* dialog I selected *Hosts* and switched it to *Run tests in 64 bit process on 64 bit machine*.

Comment: I got this problem again today, and once again, uninstalled .NET 4.5 and installed .NET 4, and it fixed my MSTest.

Comment: I'm beginning to think that my particular Unit Testing troubles are coming from Typemock.  Some of my tests only work if I disable Typemock.

Comment: The change to run tests in 64 bit process worked for my issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is possibly because you have previously run your tests and stopped them before they completed (possibly because you were debugging and you hit a breakpoint) leaving the test agent process still running, you are then unable to start a second instance. The name of the process escapes me at the moment but if find the process in task manager and kill it off, this will hopefully solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The agent is QTAgent32.exe. But it doesn't seem to be running. Killing all the processes pertaining to Visual Studio 2010 and restarting the IDE doesn't seem to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem in VS 2008. I solved it only after disabling second network adapter (or all adapters except one). Try, it might help for VS 2010 too.

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting this error in VS 2013 RC (it's in beta), and have found that closing and reopening VS causes it to go away.