# VS2010 Test Runner - Unable to start agent process

Tags: visual-studio-2010, mstest

I can't run any tess in VS2010.  Even tests that have run before.  I remember setting some services to manual start a few weeks ago, but can't remember what!

**Problem:  Which agent process / service do I need to start to make this work?**

Edit:  Even after uninstalling and reinstalling Studio2010 (and taking off the Novell Netware Client which I though may be an issue) it still doesn't work.

[image]

Comment: Did you try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3104428/failed-to-queue-test-run-unable-to-start-the-agent-processvisual-studio-2010

Comment: Yes - didn't make any difference... am trying more stuff now!

Comment: I can run tests.. just not in debug mode.  qtagent32?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it!  Avira Antivirus (even when 'disabled') seemed to be the culprit.  Uninstall of the Antivirus made everything work again.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using VS2015, I was experiencing the exact same error as the original poster (OP).  My solution turned out to be simply turning on the add-on's within Internet Explorer so that I could start recording proper tests of my webapp.  There were 3 or 4 add-on's that I simply had to enable.  After I did that, this error "Unable to start agent process" never came back.